# During Ping command what kind of packet they are going to send?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

During Ping command what kind of packet they are going to send ? I got output like this:

19 packets transmitted, 19 received, 0% packet loss, time 18006ms

so what is strategy behind this . also I want to know how I come to know that my packet is receiving at remote destination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does 'ping' command really work?](http://superuser.com/questions/278498/how-does-ping-command-really-work)

Comment: tl;dr; -  ping sends a packet containing an ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to a computer, which replies with an ECHO_REPLY packet in return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ping operates by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) Echo Request packets to the target host and waiting for an ICMP Echo Reply. The program reports errors, packet loss, and a statistical summary of the results, typically including the minimum, maximum, the mean round-trip times, and standard deviation of the mean. If all sent packets are echoed back, the destination is alive.

In short, ping is actually two different ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) packets. To ping a host you first send a ICMP Echo Request Packet, the host will then reply with an ICMP Echo Reply.

I don't exactly know that my packets are received, I just assume that when I get a reply. Quite similar to me asking you a question and not knowing whether you have heard me till you reply.

Comment: ok thank you  .Can you help me in the flow where ipv4 is coming from local host and going to be destination port as remote host using terminal ?

Comment: @Avanibadheka Ask a separate question please, and accept this answer (by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer) if it satisfies you. Remember this for all your future questions (as you're a new user).

Comment: Did you ask a separate question for the one you asked just now?

Comment: I can not add more than one questions within 40 minutes . I will add it later on

Comment: I have added my question at (http://superuser.com/questions/1117872/flow-of-ipv4-packet-travelling-through-newtwork")